# java runtime error (NZEC)

Tags: java

So i am working on this ATM problem on codechef and my program runs on my compiler and meets all the problem's requirement however codechef's compiler keeps giving me this NZEC runtime error and i cant figure out why.  Here is the code: How can i fix it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ATM {

  public static final double charge = 0.50;

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    int x,y;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (keyboard.hasNext()) {

      x = keyboard.nextInt();
      y = keyboard.nextInt();

      if( y > x + charge && x % 5 == 0) {

        double balance = y - x - charge;
        System.out.println(balance + "0");
      } else {
        System.out.println(y);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the scanner object in CodeChef. Use BufferedReader instead.

Comment: But will that fix the problem?

Comment: can you please correct the code for me then with the BufferReader cos i am still unable to get it.                                                                           Bear with me please, still a beginner

Comment: Can you show how this would be implemented, it will improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. An answer must be complete with all the information and explanations necessary to solve the problem, possibly together with some code samples.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you did not choose proper data types for your input. Your second input, i.e, y should be of `double type`, not `int type`. Then you are not printing your answer in the proper format required by Codechef. Codechef strictly follows the format in which it accepts the answer. Here, your answer must display an output of double/float data type with exactly two decimal places.

Here, I have rectified your mistakes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ATM {

  public static final double charge = 0.50;

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    int x;
    double y;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (keyboard.hasNext()) {

      x = keyboard.nextInt();
      y = keyboard.nextDouble();

      if( y > x + charge && x % 5 == 0) {

        double balance = y - x - charge;
        System.out.printf("%.2f",balance);
      } else {
        System.out.printf("%.2f",y);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Keep coding :)